# Is it possible not to show the arguments in a specific parametrized test function?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest's paremetrized test function like this

```
# imports

LONG_STRING = "hello world " * 10000

@mark.parametrize("a,c,b", [[LONG_STRING, 2, 3], [LONG_STRING, 2, 3]])
def test_something(a, b, c):
    # test whatever
```

Now, when I run this test function, I see the value of `LONG_STRING` in the stdout. Is there a way not to show this argument for this **specific** test function (so I don't want to disable this for all test functions)?

I've noticed that pytest sometimes shows the value (e.g. in the case above), but it doesn't always show the value. For example, if the argument is a list or dictionary, then it shows the parameter name rather than its value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean the output of the parameter value as part of the test name here.
You cannot completely "disable" this string in the output, but you can replace it by something else by using the [`ids` argument](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids):

```py
def id_str(param):
    if param == LONG_STRING:
        return "foo"
    # returning None just uses the default

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a,c,b", [[LONG_STRING, 2, 3], [LONG_STRING, 2, 3]],
                         ids=id_str)
def test_something(a, b, c):
    pass
```

This would result in an output something like this:

```
test_something.py::test_something[foo-2-30] 
test_something.py::test_something[foo-2-31]
```

Note that you can't get rid of the hyphen between the parameter names, so if would use an empty string instead of "foo", you would get:

```
test_something.py::test_something[-2-30] 
test_something.py::test_something[-2-31]
```

what may not be what you want.